# How to get rid of iOS 7.x (downloaded but not installed) from 6.x

Tags: ios, software-update, firmware, ipsw

As I've pointed it out in the question title, my 16 GiB iPhone 4s is getting out of memory due to the fact that it has self-downloaded iOS 7(.1.2) without I'd never asked for.

As long as it weights several GiB, there's any way to get rid of it ?
I've tried to navigate the file system through an app (for OS X) called "iFunBox", but there's no way to locate it.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. iFunbox (or equivalent) will not have access to the root filesystem. You will need to jailbreak the device for this, and none exist for iOS 8 at this time.

However, note that even if you do remove the update, iOS will still periodically check for it and redownload the firmware at a later date. You would need to prevent this and there does exist a tweak (read: hack) to accomplish this, but again, you would need to jailbreak the device.

Comment: Uhm... someone should write a letter to Apple. :/
By the way, I've iOS 6, not 8. :)

Do you think that it will download again even if I've managed to block automatic download (from the App store preference panel) ?